# Maze genorator skips spots?

Tags: java, arraylist, generator, multidimensional-array, maze

My code(Shown Below) is doing what it's supposed to do (generate a passageway from point a to b with random stops in between) and It works. Well, not all of the time. I have tried to research for syntax problems, and spent hours on end looking for some simple math problem, but I can't find it.

The Probolem is that it generates a valid path most of the time, but ocationaly, it is 3 spots off from the first point to the second. Does anyone see what the issue is?

```
    public static int[][] genLayer(int enterX, int enterY) {

    // Initiate Variables and arrays
    ArrayList<Integer> xPos = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Array of x
                                                        // positions
    ArrayList<Integer> yPos = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Array of y
                                                        // positions

    int[][] layer = new int[20][20]; // The 2D array of the layer to be
                                        // returned to the caller

    // Generates the points for the passageway to go thru.
    int point1X = rand.nextInt(20); // The first point's x
    int point1Y = rand.nextInt(20); // The first point's y
    int point2X = rand.nextInt(20); // The second point's x
    int point2Y = rand.nextInt(20); // The second point's y
    int point3X = rand.nextInt(20); // The third point's x
    int point3Y = rand.nextInt(20); // The third point's y

    layer[enterX][enterY] = 4; // Set the cords of enter X and Y to 4, the
                                // number representing the up stairs

    // Enter To Point 1:

    // Generate the first set of x points for the layer's passages
    if (enterX > point1X) {

        for (int x = enterX - 1; x > point1X; x--) {
            xPos.add(x);
        }

    } else if (enterX < point1X) {

        for (int x = enterX + 1; x < point1X; x++) {
            xPos.add(x);
        }

    }

    // Generate the first set of y points for the layer's passages
    if (enterY > point1Y) {

        for (int y = enterY - 1; y > point1Y; y--) {
            yPos.add(y);
        }

    } else if (enterY < point1Y) {

        for (int y = enterY + 1; y < point1Y; y++) {
            yPos.add(y);
        }

    }

    // Make Passages
    if (yPos.size() > 0) {
        if (rand.nextBoolean() & xPos.size() > 0) { // Chose randomly
                                                    // whether to
                                                    // make the passage up
                                                    // then
                                                    // sideways or sideways
                                                    // then
                                                    // up.
                                                    //
                                                    // Then, decide if there
                                                    // is
                                                    // any horizontal or
                                                    // vertical passages to
                                                    // generate
            // x then y

            for (int i = 0; i < xPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(i)][enterY] = 1; // make the horizontal
                                                // passage

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < yPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(xPos.size() - 1)][yPos.get(i)] = 1; // make
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // vertical
                                                                    // passage

            }

        } else {

            // y then x

            for (int i = 0; i < yPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[enterX][yPos.get(i)] = 1; // make the vertical passage

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < xPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(i)][yPos.get(yPos.size() - 1)] = 1; // make
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // horizontal
                                                                    // passage

            }

        }
    }
    // Set point 1 to the last xPos and yPos to make up for unknown
    // calculation errors
    if (xPos.size() > 0)
        point1X = xPos.get(xPos.size() - 1);
    if (yPos.size() > 0)
        point1Y = yPos.get(yPos.size() - 1);

    // Flush the values of xPos and yPos
    xPos.clear();
    yPos.clear();

    // Point 1 To Point 2:

    // Generate the second set of x points for the layer's passages
    if (point1X > point2X) {

        for (int x = point1X - 1; x > point2X; x--) {
            xPos.add(x);
        }

    } else if (point1X < point2X) {

        for (int x = point1X + 1; x < point2X; x++) {
            xPos.add(x);
        }

    }

    // Generate the second set of y points for the layer's passages
    if (point1Y > point2Y) {

        for (int y = point1Y - 1; y > point2Y; y--) {
            yPos.add(y);
        }

    } else if (point1Y < point2Y) {

        for (int y = point1Y + 1; y < point2Y; y++) {
            yPos.add(y);
        }

    }

    // Make Passages
    if (yPos.size() > 0) {
        if (rand.nextBoolean() & xPos.size() > 0) { // Chose randomly
                                                    // whether to
                                                    // make the passage up
                                                    // then
                                                    // sideways or sideways
                                                    // then
                                                    // up.
                                                    //
                                                    // Then, decide if there
                                                    // is
                                                    // any horizontal or
                                                    // vertical passages to
                                                    // generate
            // x then y

            for (int i = 0; i < xPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(i)][point1Y] = 1; // make the horizontal
                                                    // passage

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < yPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(xPos.size() - 1)][yPos.get(i)] = 1; // make
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // vertical
                                                                    // passage

            }

        } else {

            // y then x

            for (int i = 0; i < yPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[point1X][yPos.get(i)] = 1; // make the vertical
                                                    // passage

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < xPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(i)][yPos.get(yPos.size() - 1)] = 1; // make
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // horizontal
                                                                    // passage

            }

        }
    }
    // Set point 2 to the last xPos and yPos to make up for unknown
    // calculation errors
    if (xPos.size() > 0)
        point2X = xPos.get(xPos.size() - 1);
    if (yPos.size() > 0)
        point2Y = yPos.get(yPos.size() - 1);

    // Flush the values of xPos and yPos
    xPos.clear();
    yPos.clear();

    // Point 2 To Point 3:

    // Generate the third set of x points for the layer's passages
    if (point2X > point3X) {

        for (int x = point2X - 1; x > point3X; x--) {
            xPos.add(x);
        }

    } else if (point2X < point3X) {

        for (int x = point2X + 1; x < point3X; x++) {
            xPos.add(x);
        }

    }

    // Generate the third set of y points for the layer's passages
    if (point2Y > point3Y) {

        for (int y = point2Y - 1; y > point3Y; y--) {
            yPos.add(y);
        }

    } else if (point2Y < point3Y) {

        for (int y = point2Y + 1; y < point3Y; y++) {
            yPos.add(y);
        }

    }

    // Make Passages
    if (yPos.size() > 0) {
        if (rand.nextBoolean() & xPos.size() > 0) { // Chose randomly
                                                    // whether to
                                                    // make the passage up
                                                    // then
                                                    // sideways or sideways
                                                    // then
                                                    // up.
                                                    //
                                                    // Then, decide if there
                                                    // is
                                                    // any horizontal or
                                                    // vertical passages to
                                                    // generate
            // x then y

            for (int i = 0; i < xPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(i)][point2Y] = 1; // make the horizontal
                                                    // passage

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < yPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(xPos.size() - 1)][yPos.get(i)] = 1; // make
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // vertical
                                                                    // passage

            }

        } else {

            // y then x

            for (int i = 0; i < yPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[point2X][yPos.get(i)] = 1; // make the vertical
                                                    // passage

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < xPos.size(); i++) {

                layer[xPos.get(i)][yPos.get(yPos.size() - 1)] = 1; // make
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // horizontal
                                                                    // passage

            }

        }
    }
    // Set point 3 to the last xPos and yPos to make up for unknown
    // calculation errors
    if (xPos.size() > 0)
        point3X = xPos.get(xPos.size() - 1);
    if (yPos.size() > 0)
        point3Y = yPos.get(yPos.size() - 1);

    // Flush the values of xPos and yPos
    xPos.clear();
    yPos.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + layer[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return layer;
}
```

Note: I know this code can be much, much smaller with methods, but this is just a rough test of it's capabilities. I will be working on that later.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mistake I notice is in the "Make Passages" sections. Each one is wrapped in an

`if(yPos.size() > 0)`

conditional, but doesn't consider the case of when `xPos.size()` is greater than zero. Basically, if there's no change in `Y`, but there is a change in `X`, then it will just skip creating that section of passage.

Example:

```
p2    p3

p1
```

results in

```
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0
```

Next bug:
If one of the variables is only off by one, then the size of the list of points it generates will be 0, so it will not connect the two. For example `enterX` equals to 10 and `point1X` equal to 9 will not connect them.

```
p3

p2
   p1
```

results in

```
1  0
1  0
0  0
0  4
```

To fix this, I'd suggest changing all of the loops of the form

```
for (int x = enterX - 1; x > point1X; x--)
```

to

```
for (int x = enterX - 1; x >= point1X; x--)
```

In other words, including the final point in the list.

Comment: This worked, making it connect most of the time, but it still, ocationaly jumps horizontaly...

Answer (score 0):

The paths you generate aren't going the entire distance between your sets of two points. Since you stop generating your path at pX - 1 and pY - 1 (in the case of positive direction traversal, and pX + 1 and pY + 1 during negative direction traversal), you get this sort of design:

```
0  0 0 P2
1  1 1 0
1  0 0 0
P1 0 0 0
```

Notice that the path doesn't actually reach P2. Try changing these sections and those like it to

```
// Generate the first set of x points for the layer's passages
if (enterX > point1X) {

    for (int x = enterX - 1; x >= point1X; x--) { // > becomes >=
        xPos.add(x);
    }

} else if (enterX < point1X) {

    for (int x = enterX + 1; x <= point1X; x++) { // < becomes <=
        xPos.add(x);
    }

}
```

so that the entire distance between the points is always traversed.